# how to record sound via headphone in audacity

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, headphones, audacity

i have tried recording sound via headphone but i cant get it done not only that but while using skype my voice is not audible to the person whom i am talking but i can hear his voice  i think it is the issue of some simple settings so can any one help me to get it done

i have connected my headphone into my pc but i cant see it in the list of recordable devices have a look at it
[image]

is this an issue of incompatible headphones ?

Comment: Head phone's have NO microphone. Only headset have it. It should have 2 plugs. Does your microphone really working in another computer or in Windows?

Comment: There exists a *Skype call recorder*

Comment: Yeah. what?? Headphones != Headsets. Headphones do not have microphones. Headsets do. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's look like that's you have no working device to record sound... just have a look on mine sound setting:

PS no microphone not headphone are plugged in, that's only show my audio pheripheral ability.

[image]

Comment: Hi @agha . Did you resolved your issue? that's a post with a similar problem  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1684203 that's the launchpad to signal the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio?field.searchtext=pulseaudio+record&search

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean headset (if you mean headphones you will require a microphone), first I would check that the headset is working on a different device. In my experience a lot of cheap headsets break very easily. If it doesn't work on another device then it is definitely going to be a hardware problem with the headset.

Next you need to check that the headset is compatible. The connector should fit snugly into the jack. If you have a single jack headset (like for a smartphone) and you are trying to plug it into a computer which is expecting separate audio output and microphone inputs then that is not going to work. If you only really care about making the audio recording it might work if you plug it into the microphone jack but I can't guarantee that. Also if you want to listen back to the recording you'll either need to keep switching between the audio output and microphone jack or get a separate audio output device.

So let's say that everything checks out you have a microphone plugged into the microphone jack (and perhaps audio output plugged into the audio output jack) and they fit properly.

Then I think they next question would be to check that you are up to date:

Try following these instructions:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

If it still isn't working try a restart.

If it still isn't working try this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
hdajackretask
```

And try a restart. After that I am out of ideas (without further input).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work? Can't help more without feedback.