# Record audio with jack

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack

I'm trying to record sound from my piano which only has 'headphones' audio output (as well as loudspeakers), so there is no USB for things like MIDI. Thus I connect the piano to my computer using a double jack cable.

I tried to record with Audacity, but I'm not able to get any sound to my computer through the jack cable : at first I only had *pulse* (and *default*) as input sources.

I installed `pulseaudio-module-jack` but that didn't help. Then I installed Ardour5 (that doesn't work at all, but that's not the point of this question) which automatically installed `qjackctl`, but the only way I found to launch  JACK was to change the default configuration : I had to change the Input and Output devices from `(default)` to `hw:PCH`.

So now I can select `JACK Audio Connection Kit` instead of `ALSA` in Audacity, but the input sources either are `system`, which gives nothing else than the built-in microphone output, or `PulseAudio JACK Sink`, which doesn't work at all (Audacity only shows a flat line).

Is there something wrong with how I configured qjackctl ? Or is there any other tool to record audio from the jack ?

**Notes :**

- I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/533620/668959), but without success ;
- I'm talking here about inputs shown in Audacity, but I checked the *Input* section under *Settings* > *Sound*, as well as *PulseAudio Volume Control*, there were no other sources.

Comment: To be honest, if you are doing recording, it is best to use a specialized distro. I use kxstudio - http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/ . you can try ubuntu studio as an alternate. Audacity never worked well for what you are doing, use Ardour

Comment: Does your laptop have a dedicated "Microphone" connector ? - you need to go from piano to that, as simply connecting two heaphone outputs won't work. If your laptop doesn't have a microphone input, you'll need to get a TRRS adapter like [this one](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1xgYzQVXXXXXvapXXq6xXFXXXo/MLLSE-3-5-Stereo-TRRS-4-Poles-Plug-To-Earphone-Headset-Mic-Audio-Adapter-For-iPhone.jpg_640x640.jpg) (mono only, may give bad sound quality), or a USB sound card (better).

Comment: @Panther I'll try a specific distro, thanks for the advice. It might be that Audacity isn't the best thing to do that, but it's not the issue here (I updated the question explaining that I checked the Input sources in the Settings as well)

Comment: @JonasCz My laptop has a combined microphone/headphones jack (female) connector. (There is a logo of both headphones and microphone under the connector, and when I connect a headset with microphone, the headset microphone works)

Comment: After my experience with audio recording I would not try to debug or tune a standard Ubuntu install for what you are doing. The AV specific distros have all the tuning out of the box, including jack so kxstudio may solve your problem .

Comment: Yes, in that case, if you look at the connector for that headset with built in mic, you'll see it most likely has 4 metal parts separated by plastic rings (it's called "trrs"- tip ring ring sleeve). One of those is for the audio from the mic - if you look at the cable you've got going from piano to computer, it's most likeley one with 3 metal parts (trs, tip ring sleve) same as regular headphones without mic, That's why that one doesn't work - your laptop expects the microphone input to be on that extra part of the connector. If you plug in a regular cable the laptop won't enable the mic input

Comment: So you'll need an adapter or a cable which sends the audio to the right places one one of those 4 part audio connectors. The version of Ubuntu or software you're using most likely has nothing to do with this - it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

So - there's an oddity in Ardour:  If you have `jackd` running in an attempt to use realtime mode, Ardour will fail.  And if you start `jack` from Ardour, Ardour will always try to start with realtime mode enabled...

The solution to this is to force `jackd` to start without realime enabled.  The easy way to do this, is to use `qjackctl` and in it's setup, un-check the realtime mode checkbox:

[image]

Comment: This is because you need to set ardour to the Audio group to give it realtime access. When this q was written it was a bit more complicated and involved editing security.d files, but ardour provided a solution with version 5.